# Jquery multiple selectors within one function using data-attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a Jquery on() handler with a click event. In the function I get the data attribute that is in the selector's **a** tag, like so:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.video-thumbnail a' ,function(){
  var videoID =  $(this).attr('data-video-id');
  //more data atts etc.
});
```

My HTML is like so: (times ~ *20)

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="video-thumbnail">
      <a data-video-id="123"><img></a>
    </div>
    <div class="video-title">
      <a>title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="video-watch">
      <a>Watch</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is that every anchor in the div ".block" have the same click event handler, but I can still use the data-attr from the first anchor (either using `this` or something else).

So: no matter what anchor the user clicks on within that div; they all execute the same jquery function using the same data-attr.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: It seems to me like you should alter your structure. The data-video-id attribute appears to belong to the whole `.block` and it might be more appropriate if it were an attribute of `.block` rather than of the anchor.

Answer (score 4):

So, if I'm understanding correctly, you want to attach event handlers to all anchors, but always get the attribute from the `.video-thumbnail` `<div>`. You'd be best off using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.block div a' ,function(){
    var videoID = $(this).closest('.block').find('.video-thumbnail a').attr('data-video-id');
})
```

Please note the other errors in your code:

- You need a closing parenthesis at the end of your jQuery
- You need to close your `class` attribute on your `.video-thumbnail` element.

As already mentioned by [76484](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828621/jquery-multiple-selectors-within-one-function-using-data-attributes#comment42227465_26828621) it would semantically make much more sense to have each block hold the `data-video-id` attribute, since that is the upper-most context for each video.

Comment: I will try that, thank you. You can ignore the errors in the code, I just wrote it quickly for this post to get the point across.

Comment: @Cooleronie Glad to have helped.